# Java Processing Large Data Files Efficiently

Tags: java, io, large-files, binary-data, memory-mapped-files

I need a way to process large binary data files efficiently, both in terms of memory and time.

I am working on a multi-threaded Java application that processes large binary data files comprised of many data points that are many-dimensional. The data points have the same dimension, and each point is about 100 kb. The number of data points is roughly 10,000 to 100,000. The data files are several gigabytes in the testing phase, but they will be many gigabytes in the future.

The customer is running into memory problems when running the application, so I am working on a List of data points that decreases the memory required for processing while still providing good performance.

Java is a requirement of the project, and we constrained by the current memory on the client's system. The client system has many cores, but it is a shared system, and memory is the limiting factor right now.

The set of data points is used repeatedly in our application. Sometimes the points are processed sequentially. At other times, subsets of the points, including all combinations of two distinct points, are processed. Within a subset, the points can be processed in any order, but points in a subset may be arbitrarily far apart. The data files are simple binary files I produce by parsing text data files and writing the values to a binary file. Currently, the data is double-precision, so I write the data points consecutively as a series of doubles to the binary data file. (I parse each text file data point and write it immediately to the binary file, rather than keeping them all in memory.) In the future we may process float, int, etc. data.

I've searched SO and other Internet sites. I've tried several approaches so far, including reading points from the binary file as needed, but the performance has been poor compared to keeping the List of all data points in memory simultaneously. That works well for tests with smaller numbers of points of smaller dimensions, but the data sets for those tests are several orders of magnitude smaller than the real data sets. The approaches I have tried so far are hundreds or thousands of times slower than keeping all the points in memory.

I have experimented with direct ByteBuffers and MappedByteBuffers. The best approach is a class that I have extracted the relevant parts of below. It reads the binary data into an array of MappedByteBuffers. Then when a data point is requested through the get(int index) method below, the method loads the relevant buffer, reads the relevant bytes into a byte array, converts the bytes into a double array, and creates a DataPoint object. I used an array of MappedByteBuffers since there is no way the entire data file will fit into physical memory. I used an array of byte arrays so that the threads would have separate byte arrays to read the data into. Then I synchronized only on the actual access to the MappedByteBuffer, to minimize blocking. As I understand the Java Class Library, a Buffer is not threads-safe, though I read a post recently that claimed that MappedByteBuffers don't need to be synchronized.

Any feedback is welcome. In particular, I am curious about synchronization of the MappedByteBuffers.

```
final static private int DOUBLE_BYTE_SIZE = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

public enum DataType {
  CHAR,
  DOUBLE,
  FLOAT,
  INT,
  LONG,
  SHORT;
}

final static private int numberOfBuffers = 8;
private MappedByteBuffer[] buffers = null;
private int bufferSize = -1;
private byte[][] readArray = null;
private DataType dataType;
private int sizeOfVector;
private int byteSizeOfVector;
private File binFile;
private int size = -1;

private int makeList(File binaryFile, DataType argDataType, int numberOfComponents) {
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  FileChannel fc = null;
  try {
    dataType = argDataType;
    sizeOfVector = numberOfComponents;
    fis = new FileInputStream(binaryFile);
    fc = fis.getChannel();
    long fileSize = fc.size();

    switch (dataType) {
    case DOUBLE:
      byteSizeOfVector = DOUBLE_BYTE_SIZE * sizeOfVector;
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

    size = (int) fileSize / byteSizeOfVector;
    bufferSize = size / numberOfBuffers;
    buffers = new MappedByteBuffer[numberOfBuffers];
    long remaining = fileSize;
    long position = 0;
    int bufferNumber = 0;
    while(remaining > 0) {
      long length = Math.min(remaining, bufferSize * byteSizeOfVector);
      buffers[bufferNumber] = fc.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, position, length);
      position += length;   
      remaining -= length;
      bufferNumber++;
    }
    readArray = new byte[numberOfBuffers][byteSizeOfVector];

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    return -1;
  } finally {
    try {
      if(fis != null) {
        fis.close();
      }

      if(fc != null) {
        fc.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException exClose) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

private static long makeLong(byte[] data) {
  if (data == null || data.length != 8) return 0x0;

  return (long)(
      (long) (0xFF & data[0]) << 56  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[1]) << 48  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[2]) << 40  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[3]) << 32  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[4]) << 24  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[5]) << 16  |
      (long) (0xFF & data[6]) << 8   |
      (long) (0xFF & data[7]) << 0
      );
}  

private static double makeDouble(byte[] data) {
  if (data == null || data.length != 8) return 0x0;
  return Double.longBitsToDouble(makeLong(data));
}

private static double[] makeDoubleArray(byte[] data) {
  if (data == null) return null;
  if (data.length % 8 != 0) return null;

  double[] doubleArray = new double[data.length / 8];

  for (int index = 0; index < dbls.length; index++) {
    doubleArray[index] = makeDouble(new byte[] {
        data[(index*8)],
        data[(index*8)+1],
        data[(index*8)+2],
        data[(index*8)+3],
        data[(index*8)+4],
        data[(index*8)+5],
        data[(index*8)+6],
        data[(index*8)+7],
    }
        );
  }
  return doubleArray;
}

@Override
public DataPoint get(int index) {
  if(index > size() - 1) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index exceeds length of list.");
  } else if(index < 0) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index is less than zero.");
  }

  int bufferNumber = index / bufferSize;
  int bufferPosition = index % bufferSize;
  MappedByteBuffer buffer = buffers[bufferNumber];
  synchronized (buffer) {
    buffer.load();
    buffer.position(bufferPosition * sizeOfVector);
    buffer.get(readArray[bufferNumber]);
  }

  switch(dataType) {
  case DOUBLE:
    return new DoublePoint(makeDoubleArray(readArray[bufferNumber]));
  default:
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: My 2 cents: if it does not fit in memory, read your data points and stash them in a cache that overflows to a store (filesystem, etc...). [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is one of them. The cache maintains indexes for "fast" retrieval and will manage the memory for you.

Comment: The only question I see here is whether `ByteBuffer` needs synchronization. The answer is that is "yes," *if you are willing to depend on implementation details and limit yourself to absolute positioning and read-only access*. But that doesn't seem to be the question that you want answered. If I had to guess, your real question is "can I avoid the cost of paging if I don't have enough RAM to hold my data," and the answer to that should be obvious.